# Create a new column applying multiple conditions

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column from other existing columns in my data.frame

For instance, imagine that I have 3 columns: a,b,c

```
a <- c(1,0,0,0,1) 
b <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
c <- c(0,0,1,1,0)
```

I want to create a new column called "Category" by using a condition that starts looking at column a, if a=1 then "A" if a=0 then go to column b, if b=1 then "B" if b=0 then go to column c, if c=1 then "C". An important thing to know is that my actual data if there is a column that contains 1, the other two columns are 0 automatically. Or maybe it is more simple to do it with a function?

So I'd like a result like the following:

```
Category <- c("A","B","C","C","A")
```

Comment: `Category <- ifelse(a == 1, "A", ifelse(b == 1, "B", "C"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

a <- c(1,0,0,0,1) 
b <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
c <- c(0,0,1,1,0)

df <- tibble(a, b, c)

df %>%
  mutate(Category = pmap(list(a, b, c), ~ names(df)[c(...) == 1])) %>%
  unnest(cols = "Category") %>%
  mutate(Category = str_to_upper(Category))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
      a     b     c Category
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1     1     0     0 A       
2     0     1     0 B       
3     0     0     1 C       
4     0     0     1 C       
5     1     0     0 A
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `pivot_longer()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(a, b, c)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  select(-value)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   name      a     b     c
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1     0     0
# 2 b         0     1     0
# 3 c         0     0     1
# 4 c         0     0     1
# 5 a         1     0     0
```